# Calling and modifying strings from a separate file

Tags: python

I'm trying to house url's in a separate file to make the main file easier to read. My issue is trying to call a url and add text I want to it. My code currently looks like this:

```
**urls.py:**
def addressList(input):
    a = f'www.url.com/{input}'
    b = f'www.differenturl.com/{input}'
    c = f'www.thirdUrl.com/{input}'

**main.py**:
import urls

def mainFunction():
    return(urls.addressList('my_text_here').a   #I expected this to return "www.url.com/my_text_here but 
it throws "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'"
```

How can I access the variables inside of a function in a different file, or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: What did you expect? Those variable are deleted when the function returns None. Maybe you need a `dict`.

Comment: You can't access an internal variable.  You have to `return` the desired value from `addressList`.  The error message slaps you because you returned the default value of `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return` values if you want to use them outside the function.

```
def addressList(input):
    return dict(
        a = f'www.url.com/{input}',
        b = f'www.differenturl.com/{input}',
        c = f'www.thirdUrl.com/{input}',
    )
```

```
def mainFunction():
    return urls.addressList('my_text_here')['a']
```

If you want to be able to have named attributes instead of using dictionary keys, `NamedTuple` is great:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class AddressList(NamedTuple):
    a: str
    b: str
    c: str

def address_list(input: str) -> AddressList:
    return AddressList(
        f'www.url.com/{input}',
        f'www.differenturl.com/{input}',
        f'www.thirdUrl.com/{input}',
    )
```

```
def mainFunction() -> str:
    return urls.addressList('my_text_here').a
```